# Umbraco Model Builder Missing

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I worked on exists umbraco project, and in this project there is a model builder button that generate model and I can copy them to my visual studio and use them as model.

Now I started a new project, but In the new App I don't have the generate model button

This is my Previous Project
[image]
And this is my current project (without the generate model button)
[image]

How can I add models builder to my project, And How can I know which model builder uses on my previous project.

Comment: Pretty sure the models are autogenerated now, whenever you save a doctype. Check /App_Data/Models/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **PureLive** models configuration set up, which means exactly that your models are autogenerated and you don't need to fire it up via button. It may be helpful but also dangerous :)

The configuration is in you *web.config* file and you can change the mode of storing models there.

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />
```

Check more info at Stephan's Wiki: https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki/UsingTheModelsBuilder and choose the best way to handle models inside your instance of Umbraco.

Comment: I Change the  <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="PureLive" /> to  <add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="AppData" /> And its mork thanks!